Charging scheduling of electric vehicle by TD3 algorithm(RL)
I set three reward values, namely r_anx, r_dep and r_price, in which r_dep<=0, and obtained corresponding reward values by setting different weight coefficients. However, two situations would occur. (1) The three reward values showed an upward trend, but I tried to make r_dep as 0 as possible, which did not achieve my expected effect. (2)r_dep and r_anx increase, but r_price decreases.
[enter image description here](https://i.s[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/amExA.png)tack.imgur.com/ZZK4J.png)
May I ask how to solve the above problems, so that the three reward values are all rising trend, and r_dep is as close as possible to 0.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
